# Google Apps Script как сделать чтобы скрипт понимал числа из формулы

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть скрит для гугл таблиц который проверяет числа в столбце с названием "**Сумма**" и если число больше 5, то присылает уведомление в телеграм.

Данный код реагирует только на изменения чисел редактированием в ручном режиме в листе.

Как нужно изменить код скрипта чтобы он понимал числа в столбце с названием "**Сумма**"  которые образованные с помощтю формул и присылал бы уведомления, как и при ручном редактировании числа?

```
function onChange(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName('My'); // название листа
  var token = "6362357049zxHBHeO4"; // токен бота
  var chatId = "-114165"; // chat_id

  var range = e.range;
  var sheetName = range.getSheet().getName();
  var cellAddress = range.getA1Notation();
  var editedValue = e.value;
  var targetColumn = "Сумма";
  var targetValue = 5;

  // Проверка, попадает ли измененная ячейка в целевой столбец
  if (sheetName === 'My' && range.getColumn() == getColByName(sheet, targetColumn) && editedValue > targetValue) {
    sendTelegramMessage("Значение в столбце 'Сумма' превысило " + targetValue + ": " + editedValue);
  }
}

function sendTelegramMessage(message) {
  var token = "6362xHBHeO4";
  var chatId = "-104545465";

  var url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chatId + "&text=" + encodeURIComponent(message);
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
}

// Функция для получения номера столбца по его названию
function getColByName(sheet, colName) {
  var col = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].indexOf(colName) + 1;
  return col;
}
```

Заранее благодарен за помощь